# Trouble launching new Android activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity

I'm having some trouble with launching a new Android activity with code written in Eclipse. I am trying to launch my PrinterDriver activity from my main activity named HomeActivity. However, it crashes and I'm not sure why.

The code in HomeActivity is

```
public void PrintMessage(StringBuilder sb) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PrinterDriver.class);
    String message = sb.toString();
    intent.putExtra("PrintableString", message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The code in PrinterDriver is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.printing);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String sb = intent.getExtras().getString("PrintableString");
    new AlertDialog.Builder(PrinterDriver.this).setMessage(sb.toString()).show();
```

}

My manifest file code for PrinterDriver activity is

```
    <activity android:name="com.handpoint.headstart.android.PrinterDriver"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.handpoint.headstart.android.PrinterDriver" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

The code never seems to get as far as the onCreate method in PrinterDriver. I've placed a breakpoint at the startActivity function and it's getting to there OK but no further. In the Eclipse Debug environment I get the message, "the jar file c:\google android sdk\platforms\android-14\android.jar has no source attachment".

Where am I going wrong here?

Thanks in advance for your help

Edit:

My log cat error messages:

```
11-12 14:25:13.933: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(10629): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
11-12 14:25:15.875: E/MP-Decision(1702): num online cores: 1 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:1.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 68
11-12 14:25:15.875: E/MP-Decision(1702): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:0.000000
11-12 14:25:16.476: E/MP-Decision(1702): num online cores: 2 reqd : 1 available : 4 rq_depth:0.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 29
11-12 14:25:16.476: E/MP-Decision(1702): DOWN cpu:1 core_idx:1 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 total_time_down:196.000000
11-12 14:25:17.287: E/MP-Decision(1702): num online cores: 1 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:1.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 62
11-12 14:25:17.287: E/MP-Decision(1702): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:0.000000
11-12 14:25:17.727: E/MP-Decision(1702): num online cores: 2 reqd : 1 available : 4 rq_depth:0.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 11
11-12 14:25:17.727: E/MP-Decision(1702): DOWN cpu:1 core_idx:1 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 total_time_down:196.000000
11-12 14:25:17.937: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(10629): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.handpoint.headstart.sample/com.handpoint.headstart.sample.PrinterDriver}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1635)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3391)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3626)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3594)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at com.handpoint.headstart.sample.ui.HomeActivity.PrintMessage(HomeActivity.java:1100)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at com.handpoint.headstart.sample.ui.HomeActivity$10$1.onClick(HomeActivity.java:1082)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:976)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1519)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3291)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4340)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
11-12 14:25:19.048: E/AndroidRuntime(11031):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-12 14:25:19.389: E/MP-Decision(1702): num online cores: 1 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:1.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 53
11-12 14:25:19.389: E/MP-Decision(1702): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:0.000000
11-12 14:25:19.409: E/android.os.Debug(780): !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
11-12 14:25:19.789: E/MP-Decision(1702): num online cores: 2 reqd : 1 available : 4 rq_depth:1.000000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 11
11-12 14:25:19.789: E/MP-Decision(1702): DOWN cpu:1 core_idx:1 Ns:1.100000 Ts:190 total_time_down:49.000000
11-12 14:25:20.710: E/MP-Decision(1702): num online cores: 1 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:2.500000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 49
11-12 14:25:20.710: E/MP-Decision(1702): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:147.000000
11-12 14:25:20.910: E/MP-Decision(1702): num online cores: 2 reqd : 3 available : 4 rq_depth:2.700000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 79
11-12 14:25:20.910: E/MP-Decision(1702): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:0.000000
11-12 14:25:20.910: E/MP-Decision(1702): UP cpu:2 core_idx:2 Nw:2.700000 Tw:90 total_time_up:137.000000
11-12 14:25:21.161: E/MP-Decision(1702): num online cores: 3 reqd : 2 available : 4 rq_depth:1.300000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 66
11-12 14:25:21.161: E/MP-Decision(1702): DOWN cpu:2 core_idx:2 Ns:2.100000 Ts:240 total_time_down:242.000000
11-12 14:25:21.761: E/QSEECOMAPI:(11198): Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
11-12 14:25:21.761: E/QSEECOMAPI:(11198): Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
11-12 14:25:21.761: E/QSEECOMAPI:(11198): Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
11-12 14:25:21.761: E/QSEECOMAPI:(11198): Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
11-12 14:25:21.761: E/QSEECOMAPI:(11198): Error::Failed to open /dev/qseecom device
11-12 14:25:21.931: E/QcrilMsgTunnelSocket(10629): IOExceptionjava.io.IOException: No such file or directoryReason: No such file or directory
11-12 14:25:22.562: E/MP-Decision(1702): num online cores: 2 reqd : 3 available : 4 rq_depth:3.300000 hotplug_avg_load_dw: 101
11-12 14:25:22.562: E/MP-Decision(1702): UP cpu:1 core_idx:1 Nw:1.900000 Tw:140 total_time_up:0.000000
11-12 14:25:22.562: E/MP-Decision(1702): UP cpu:2 core_idx:2 Nw:2.700000 Tw:90 total_time_up:98.000000
```

Comment: is log cat showing any error?

Comment: You need to post the logcat

Comment: Check your R.layout.printing file some view tags may be in small letter.. example instead of TextView may be written as textView

Comment: post your log cat man

Comment: Could it be because the two activities reside in different packages within the src folder?

Comment: Hi All,

Thanks for your help. I have found the problem. It was a typo in the android:name parameter in the manifest file.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Window -> Android SDK Manager -> install "Sources for Android SDK" under Android 4.0
2. When prompted by "No sources attached...", click the button, then choose the Directory "your Android SDK directory/sources/android-API level/"

Example: C:...\android-sdk-windows\sources\android-16

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have problem with the import section in your code. Because the log says that it couldn't find the pass directory of your activity.
This is the pass that system is trying to find `com.handpoint.headstart.sample.PrinterDriver` but what you defined in your manifest is `com.handpoint.headstart.android.PrinterDriver` which is different from the another one